# Inserting XML document from SQL SERVER to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle, toad

I have a table in SQL Server with a XML column type. In XML column I am storing a XML document. I want to create the same table in Oracle using Toad for Oracle, but in Toad for Oracle there is no XML column type. Reason for this is to transfer a data from SQL Server to Oracle for further processing and reporting. What type of column I need to create in Oracle to insert XML document?

Comment: XMLTYPE is the data type in oracle to store xmldocs

Comment: Praneeth, sorry for my late reply, I was testing. I create XML column as XMLTYPE and I successfully inserted data from SQL to Oracle in XML column. In XML column write (HUGECLOB) and when I click twice on it I can see XML document. Thank you a lot Praneeth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have toad, but in SQL Developer there isn't an option to create a xmltype column in their graphical table creator.  You'll have to manually create it by executing a script.  You can also store an xml document in a CLOB datatype depending on your needs for the document.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm

Comment: JDro04, thank you for your answer. I use XMLTYPE , who proposed Praaneth and it works perfectly.

Comment: After a while of testing, I have had to change datatype from XMLTYPE to CLOB, because size of my XML in some cases is over 4000 characters and I am using PL/SQL to insert into table. So CLOB is better solution. Thank you.